# Test class destructor for pointer being allocated?

Tags: c++, pointers, c++11

So I am having a problem with my code. I want to pass a value from my array of pointers to a function so the original object is not 'disturbed' (my code works perfectly fine if I pass the reference; I just am just trying to do it a different way as a learning exercise). After the implementation returns, I get an error:

"error for object 0x100105790: pointer being freed was not allocated
*** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug".

I know this is because as the value goes out of scope upon the function's return, the destructor is called for the object but my destructor assumes a pointer that was allocated, thus the error. I was curious if there was a way to test if the genome was already allocated or not. If not I would do something else for the destructor? Is this even a problem worth bothering about since I already have it working by passing in the reference? The function is not actually destructive; I just have a desire to do some tricks. I don't like taking the easy way out.

```
//class destructor for int genome[]
Organism::~Organism() {
    //cout << "Deleting this: " << this << endl;
    if (this->genome != NULL) {
         delete [] this->genome;
    }
}

//declare genome pointer
int *genome;
/**
 * Default constructor for class
 */
Organism::Organism() {
    this->fitness = 0;
    this->size = 0;
    this->genome = NULL;
}
//another constructor for if only the size of genome is defined
Organism::Organism(int size) {
    this->fitness = 0;
    this->size = size;
    this->genome = new int[size];
}
//another constructor for when all starting values are defined
Organism::Organism(int size, int *genome) {
    this->fitness = 0;
    this->size = size;
    this->genome = new int[size];

    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        this->genome[i] = genome[i];
    }
 }

//initialize and populate reproducible from already existing array start_pop     (this has been verified as being properly allocated and values initiated)
vector<Organism*> reproduceable (0);
    for (int i = 0; i < start_pop.size(); i++) {
        if (start_pop[i]->get_fitness() > threshold) {
            reproduceable.push_back(start_pop[i]);
        }
    }

//function definition
Organism* reproduce(Organism, Organism);

//function call in main()
offspring.push_back(reproduce(*reproduceable[i], *reproduceable[i+1]));

//function implementation
Organism* reproduce(Organism a, Organism b) {
    int genome[4];

    //randomly decide on where to split parent genomes
    int split = rand() % 5;
    for (int i = 0; i < a.get_size(); i++) {
        if (i < split) {
            genome[i] = a.get_genome()[i];
        } else {
            genome[i] = b.get_genome()[i];
        }
    }
    //now cause random mutation in 2% of the population
    if ((rand() % 100 + 1) <= 2) {
        int rand_index = rand() % 5;
        int mutation = rand() % 6 + 1;

        genome[rand_index] = mutation;
    }

    Organism *child = new Organism(4, genome); //need to add genome
    return child;
}
```

**Edited to add default constructors and array initialization for reproducible**

Comment: What's Organism::genome? Where is it assigned to?

Comment: Being that the only `delete` is in the destructor and is trying to deallocate the `genome` array, it's possible you don't ever allocate it with `new`, hence the error. Could you post where you initialize the `reproducable` structure and the initialization of `genome` within `Organism`?

Comment: How does your constructor look like?

Comment: ``Organism* reproduce(Organism a, Organism b)`` You have pass by value parameters. Hence, the Orgamism instances get copied. And after the call, destroyed. That might be your problem. Try passing by const reference instead.

Comment: way to little information to solve this. do you have copy constructor & assignment operator?. how does the constructor look like, esp the one that takes an `int` and a `int*`. etc

Comment: The main mistake is that he is using raw pointers where ``std::shared_ptr`` and family would rule out a lot of error classes from his code.

Comment: @BitTickler , I'm even suspecting that OP just has the `genome` array allocated on the stack with something like `int genome[4];`

Comment: Aside from the original problem, this line of code: `int rand_index = rand() % 5;` may assign 4 to `rand_index`, and you would thus be accessing past the array boundaries which may introduce a host of other problems

Comment: He shows all symptoms of a student who had java classes prior to his C++ classes ;)

Comment: @BitTickler, passing by const reference works perfectly fine; I'm just curious if I can do it by value instead. I realize that there are libraries for C++ that take care of pointer allocation and destruction, but I have a strong C background and enjoy using raw pointers and basic memory manipulation in my code. I realize in a production environment I should use a library but for this I'm just playing and practicing my skills. Also I declare genome on heap space. I added my declaration code in the post.

Comment: I am thinking that @sp2danny has a point. I never explicitly declared a copy constructor or assignment operator, so that would definitely give me problems from the sound of it. I'm not familiar with those operators though so I have not yet included them in my code as I did not know why I needed them previously.

Comment: @JoshBernitt This is known as the rule of  3 or of 5 or of N, depending on C++ standard version :) Once you need to add one of them you better add them all. In your case you need the copy constructor and assignment operator as your instance is not trivially copy-able. (Your raw pointer member). If instead of adding all those extra noisy c++ operators you opt for keeping it simple, simply define your ``genome`` member as: ``std::vector<int> genome;`` and you can even get rid of the destructor.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in this line:

```
offspring.push_back(reproduce(*reproduceable[i], *reproduceable[i+1]));
```

Note that you pass two `reproduceable`s by value into a function. The function's signature is

```
Organism* reproduce(Organism a, Organism b)
```

It expects two `Organism`'s by value, which means that for both `Organism`'s a copy constructor will be called. Since you do not define a copy constructor, a default one will be created, that just copies the content of one organism into another, including a pointer go the genome. The issue is that now both `Organism`s will be freed -- the one that's local to the function, and the one that was passed into it, resulting in double freeing the memory allocated for the genome. There are two ways to solve it:

1. Make the signature to be

```cpp
Organism* reproduce(const Organism &a, const Organism &b)
```

This way your `Organism` will not be copied, and thus will not be double freed. (based on your question I assume you already tried it, and are interested in the second solution :))

2. Implement a custom copy constructor, that creates a new array, like so

```cpp
Organism::Organism(const Organism& a)
{
     this->fitness = a.fitness;
     this->size = a.size;
     this->genome = new int[this->size];
     for (int i = 0; i < this->size; ++ i)
         this->genome[i] = a.genome[i];
}
```

This way as you pass an organism into your function, your custom copy constructor will be invoked, and the `genome` for the organism local to your function will be allocated separately.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm! I didn't really understand the importance of the copy constructor until now.

Answer (score 1):

Rule of three

If a class requires a user-defined destructor, a user-defined copy 
constructor, or a user-defined copy assignment operator, it almost 
certainly requires all three.

see http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three

Although a better approach would be **rule of zero**, i.e. you embrace value semantics. 
For this program, it would be as simple as changing the `genome` member
from `int*` to 
 `int[4]`, `std::array<int,4>` or `std::vector<int>` 
(and remove the destructor)